# Find the radius of the circle inscbribed inside the square. The distance from the side of the square to circle is (2,1)

Tags: geometry, circles, puzzle, rectangles

Find the radius of the circle inscbribed inside the square. The distance from the side of the square to circle is (2,1)[see the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP5lL.png)
[image]

Comment: An ordered pair $\;(2,1)\;$ is not "distance". It only seems to be the left lower vertex of he square is at the origin $\;(0,0)\;$ and then $\;(2,1)\;$ is a point on the circle...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915935/radius-of-a-circle-touching-a-rectangle-both-of-which-are-inside-a-square/2915987#2915987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the center at the origin we have $$x^2+ y^2=r^2$$ with the point $(-r+2, -r+1)$ on the circle.

Plugging in and simplifying the equation we get $$r^2-6r+5=0$$

The solution $r=5$ is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming the square's sides are parallel to the $\;x\,-$ axis and the $\;y\,-$ axis, and since the left lower vertex is at $\;(0,0)\;$ and the circle's equation is

$$(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2=r^2\;\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

we then get from the fact that $\;(2,1)\;$ is on the circle that

$$(2-r)^2+(1-r)^2=r^2\implies r=\ldots$$

Finish the argument

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pythagoras theorem:
$a=1$ $cm$
$b=2$ $cm$
$(r-a)^2+(r-b)^2=r^2$
$(r-1)^2+(r-2)^2=r^2$
$r^2+1-2r+r^2+4-4r=r^2$
$r^2-6r+5=0$
$r=5$ $cm$
$r=1$ $cm$
The $r=5$ $cm$ is the acceptable answer.